# Get pandas headers when rows is NaN

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I got data from sensors. And some certain period they return `blank string` to me for no reason!

During the data cleaning. I can manage to get the `NaN` column using this

`df[df.isnull().values.any(axis=1)]`

```
    Time    IL1 IL2 IL3 IN  kVA kW  kWh
12463   2018-09-17 10:30:00 63.7    78.4    53.3    25.2    NaN NaN 2039676.0
12464   2018-09-17 11:00:00 64.1    78.6    53.5    25.4    NaN NaN 2039698.0
```

How can I get `kVA and kW` out from the `DataFrame`?
Then I can find the `median` of `kVA and KW` from the other rows and replace the `NaN` with it

**My usecase:**
Right now I have to read file and find where the `NaN` columns are. It require my efforts. So I wants to automate that process by replace hardcode on column name.

```
trdb_a2_2018_df = pd.read_csv(PATH + 'dpm_trdb_a2_2018.csv', thousands=',', parse_dates=['Time'], date_parser=extract_dt)
trdb_a2_2018_df = trdb_a2_2018_df.replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True)
median_kVA = trdb_a2_2018_df['kVA'].median()
trdb_a2_2018_df = trdb_a2_2018_df['kVA'].fillna(median_kVA)
```

Comment: `Then I can find the median and replace the NaN with it` - Can you explain more? What median?

Comment: `df[['kVA','kW']][df.isnull().values.any(axis=1)]` ?

Comment: @jezrael median of `kVA and kW`. I just add it.

Comment: @anky_91 I mean string with value `kVA, kW`.

Comment: are you looking for `df.columns[df.isna().any()]` ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with `median`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,np.nan],
         'C':[7,np.nan,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

print (df)
   A    B    C  D  E  F
0  a  4.0  7.0  1  5  a
1  b  5.0  NaN  3  3  a
2  c  4.0  9.0  5  6  a
3  d  5.0  4.0  7  9  b
4  e  5.0  2.0  1  2  b
5  f  NaN  3.0  0  4  b

df1 = df.fillna(df.median())
print (df1)
   A    B    C  D  E  F
0  a  4.0  7.0  1  5  a
1  b  5.0  4.0  3  3  a
2  c  4.0  9.0  5  6  a
3  d  5.0  4.0  7  9  b
4  e  5.0  2.0  1  2  b
5  f  5.0  3.0  0  4  b
```

If want also fiter `NaN`s in columns:

```
m = df.isnull().any()
df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m].fillna(df.loc[:, m].median())
```

Alternative:

```
cols = df.columns[df.isnull().any()]
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(df[cols].median())
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.median())
B    5.0
C    4.0
D    2.0
E    4.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I have never known that pandas accepts this syntax `df1 = df.fillna(df.median())`. Please wait 4 minutes until I can click accept. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sarit - yes, it is simpliest solution, maybe for better performance if many columns and only few `NaN`s columns is possible filtering, it depends of your data mainly.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC to filter out the column headers that contain `NaN`'s use:

```
df.columns[df.isna().any()]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for you to solve this question.

- Use `pandas.DataFrame.fillna` to replace the NaN value with a certain value such as 0.
- Use `pandas.DataFrame.dropna` to get a new DataFrame by filter origin DataFrame.

Reference:

- [Pandas dropna API](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna)
- [Pandas fillna API](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that this is an initial df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'kVa': np.nan, 'kW':10.1}, {'kVa': 12.5, 'kW':14.3}, {'kVa': 16.1, 'kW':np.nan}])
In [51]: df
Out[51]:
    kVa    kW
0   NaN  10.1
1  12.5  14.3
2  16.1   NaN
```

You can use DataFrames's `.fillna()` method to replace NaN's and `.notna()` to get indexes of values other than NaN:

```
df.kVa.fillna(df.kVa[df.kVa.notna()].median(), inplace=True)
df.kW.fillna(df.kW[df.kW.notna()].median(), inplace=True)
```

Use `inplace=True` to avoid creating new Series instance.
Df after these manipulations:

```
In [54]: df
Out[54]:
    kVa    kW
0  14.3  10.1
1  12.5  14.3
2  16.1  12.2
```